# Can I consolidate these methods using C# Generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code in my base controller in an MVC app:

```
protected LookUpClient GetLookupClient() {
    return new LookUpClient(CurrentUser);
}

protected AdminClient GetAdminClient() {
    return new AdminClient(CurrentUser);
}

protected AffiliateClient GetAffiliateClient() {
    return new AffiliateClient(CurrentUser);
}

protected MembershipClient GetMembershipClient() {
    return new MembershipClient(CurrentUser);
}

protected SecurityClient GetSecurityClient() {
    return new SecurityClient();
}

protected ChauffeurClient GetChauffeurClient() {
    return new ChauffeurClient(CurrentUser);
}
```

Can I somehow consolidate it using a generic method?

**Update: SecurityClient()'s different constructor is deliberate. It does not take a user.**

Comment: SecurityClient has different constructor. Is it a typo or correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can condense them all down to:

```
protected T GetClient<T>(params object[] constructorParams) 
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), constructorParams);
}
```

Call it using:

```
AdminClient ac = GetClient<AdminClient>(CurrentUser);
LookupClient lc = GetClient<LookupClient>(CurrentUser);
SecurityClient sc = GetClient<SecurityClient>();
```

etc.

If you had all of your clients utilizing the CurrentUser (currently your example suggests that SecurityClient does not), you could remove the parameter from the method and have just:

```
protected T GetClient<T>()
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), CurrentUser);
}
```

Which simplifies your calls:

```
AdminClient ac = GetClient<AdminClient>();
```

But then you lose the ability to use it on clients that don't require the CurrentUser context...

**Addendum:** In response to your comment regarding the requirement of a parameterless constructor.  I've got some demo code that I've tested to prove there isn't a requirement for a parameterless constructor:

```
public class UserContext
{
    public string UserName { get; protected set; }
    public UserContext(string username)
    {
        UserName = username;
    }
}
public class AdminClient
{
    UserContext User { get; set; }
    public AdminClient(UserContext currentUser)
    {
        User = currentUser;
    }
}
public class SecurityClient
{
    public string Stuff { get { return "Hello World"; } }
    public SecurityClient()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static T CreateClient<T>(params object[] constructorParams)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), constructorParams);   
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserContext currentUser = new UserContext("BenAlabaster");
        AdminClient ac = CreateClient<AdminClient>(currentUser);
        SecurityClient sc = CreateClient<SecurityClient>();
    }
}
```

This code runs without any exceptions and will create the AdminClient which doesn't have a paremeterless constructor, and will also create the SecurityClient which only has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: This looks pretty dope. I am going to give it a shot. SecurityClient doesn't currently need to know the current user, but I wouldn't mind passing it in anyway. I was thinking about adding auditing and the auditing feature would need to know. Thank you for your prompt and detailed response. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hmm, the first method gives this error: "Constructor on type 'Gd2.ServicesClient.AdminClient' not found." The second method crashes the application pool and takes VS2010 down with it! Haha!

Comment: The exception appears to be related to the fact that the compiler can't identify the correct constructor of the object you're trying to create based on the parameters you're passing in the constructorParams argument(s).  Have you checked that the type of the object(s) you are passing correctly match to one of the constructors of the class that is being created?

Comment: @Chris Is the constructor on the class marked as public?  Is T identifying the correct type?  Without being able to step through the code, it's hard to say exactly what the problem is, so I'm guessing of course.

Comment: @Chris Is the constructor on the class marked as public?  Is T identifying the correct type?  Without being able to step through the code, it's hard to say exactly what the problem is, so I'm guessing of course.

Comment: I think it was bombing because parameterless constructors are required and none of my clients but SecurityClient have those (and I would like to keep it that way). I posted the error message to gsharp's answer.

Comment: It was only a guess. I get the aforementioned errors and crashes when I try to implement your code. I am sure your sample works, but I can't get it to work in my app, probably due to the fact that my clients are inheriting all kinds of stuff and implementing interfaces. I will try to pull my class definitions out into LINQPad and repeat the error in a portable codebase.

Comment: You know when you have to drop your dreams of writing cleaner code because business gets in the way? That happened to me and I may not ever get around to this. But you were the most helpful so I am crediting you with the answer. Thank you, Ben.

Comment: @Chris You're welcome. Sorry to hear about your business frustrations, alas, those go with the turf and it is unlikely you will ever get away from them completely. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had a thought about using `dynamic` to solve this.  If you could change your clients to expose CurrentUser as a property, you could potentially do something like this:

```
    protected T GetClient<T>(int CurrentUser) where T : new()
    {
        T client = new T();
        dynamic retval = client;
        retval.CurrentUser = CurrentUser;
        return retval;  
    }
```

I don't think this is any better than the suggestions above, but just presented as a different approach.

Comment: I like this, but it goes under the assumption that your new T() has a property for which to assign CurrentUser which it may not... I haven't done much experimentation with dynamic - what happens if you assign to a property that doesn't exist?

Comment: You get a `RuntimeBinderException` - that's why I don't purport this to be better than the above.  More of an exercise to think laterally. :)

Comment: Not like JavaScript which just creates said property then... that's too bad.

Comment: @Ben it does (at least the same behavior), if T is inherited from ExpandoObject

Comment: @gsharp That's sweet.  Although, that means that if your object is already derived, you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection, although this depends on the created type having a matching constructor:

```
protected T GetClient<T>()
{
    ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(User) });
    return (T)ci.Invoke(new object[] { this.CurrentUser });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid using reflection when it comes to generics, so if its possible to redesign your XYclient classes with a common base class or an interface i would do that. 
sample:

```
public interface IClient
{
    CurrentUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
}

public class LookUpClient : IClient
{
    public CurrentUser CurrentUser {get;set;}
}

public class AffiliateClient : IClient
{
    public CurrentUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    private static T GetClient<T>() where T : IClient, new()
    {
        T client = new T();
        client.CurrentUser = CurrentUser;
        return client;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lookup = GetClient<LookUpClient>();
        var affiliate = GetClient<AffiliateClient>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is totally possible for me to create a common base class at this point, but Ben's answer seems to suggest that this is not necessary. I will try his solution first. Thank you for your response, and sorry I did not clarify SecurityClient(). It does look like it could have been a typo but the parameterless constructor was intended.

Comment: Just be aware that Ben's solution is not type safe. Mine is by defining the constriant for T :-)

Comment: @Chris/@gsharp It's true, in my example, I didn't consider type safety.  Of course, this example makes other assumptions that aren't necessarily true - like your 'client' object having a CurrentUser property.  It's all swings and roundabouts, both methods have their place depending upon what you're trying to achieve in the longer term.

Comment: @Ben agree with you as you said it's all swings and roundabouts... Your solutions is actually pretty sexy ;-) I was just saying if it's possible to bring in type safety then he should do it.

Comment: I like this solution, but my clients require the CurrentUser and therefore have only a constructor that takes a user. So, the error I am getting is this: `'Gd2.ServicesClient.AffiliateClient' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Gd2.Client.Web.Controllers.Gd2Controller.GetHelperClient<T>()'` Is there a way for this to work with my constructor? Let's not worry about SecurityClient() for now.

Comment: @Chris Sadly, there's no easy way to define using new T() with optional parameters without coding around the houses.  I posted a tested example for you to reference.